# How to create a link on an image in react-native (web/android/ios)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I want to display two clickable image with **Available on App Store** and **Available on Google Play** on my landing page which I also make with `react-native-web`.

I am able to create an `<ExternalLink />` component, but it does not really look like a normal `<a>` yet (no hover or effect at the moment => ugly).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const ExternalLink = (props) => (
  <Text 
    {...props} 
    accessibilityRole="link" 
    target="_blank" 
  />
);

export default ExternalLink;
```

I have tried to use that component around an `<Image />` as you would normally do in web with `<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com"><Image src={availableOnGooglePlay} /></a>`.

More generally, how can I create a link on an image in `react-native` for all devices (iOS, Android, Web)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use any of the `Touchable` components to achieve this, I checked the RN Web docs and they've mostly been ported. Here's a small example:

```js
export default class ExternalLink extends Component {

    _openLink = async () => {
        const { link } = this.props;

        if (await Linking.canOpenURL(link)) {
            Linking.openURL(link);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity accessibilityRole='link' onPress={this._openLink}>
                {children}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like so:

```js
<ExternalLink link='YOUR_LINK_HERE'>
    <Image source='YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE' />
</ExternalLink>
```